# EF Core 2 - Only Request Two Columns

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to write a LINQ statement for EF Core 2 that only requests SQL return two columns: UserID and FirstNamePreferred.

Everything I've tried creates a SQL statement that requests all columns.

Here is my code:

```
var model = db.FamilyMember  
  .Where(fm => fm.UserID == message.CurrentUserID)
  .Select(fm => new Model
  {
      UserID = message.CurrentUserID,
      FirstNamePreferred = fm.FirstNamePreferred
  })
  .AsNoTracking()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

My view model:

```
    public class Model
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstNamePreferred { get; set; }
    }
```

This generates the following SQL via Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [fm].[ID], [fm].[DOB], [fm].[DOD], [fm].[EyeColourID], [fm].[FamilyID], [fm].[FirstName], [fm].[FirstNameKnownAs], [fm].[Gender], [fm].[HairColour], [fm].[IdentifiesAs], [fm].[LastName], [fm].[MiddleNames], [fm].[NickName], [fm].[PictureExt], [fm].[PictureUID], [fm].[PrimaryEmailAddress], [fm].[SkinTone], [fm].[UserID]
FROM [FamilyMember] AS [fm]
WHERE [fm].[UserID] = @__message_CurrentUserID_0',N'@__message_CurrentUserID_0 nvarchar(450)',@__message_CurrentUserID_0=N'b0e1fe4c-f218-4903-8117-465a68cd99fc'
```

Update: The issue was that FirstNamePreferred was not actually a database field. Sorry I didn't drill down this far in the code, rookie mistake.

```
    public string FirstNamePreferred
    {
        get
        {
            if (FirstNameKnownAs == null)
            {
                return FirstName;
            }
            else
            {
                return FirstNameKnownAs;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (EFC2.0.1, SqlServer)

Comment: You should consider adding your update as an answer so people can see the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The issue was that FirstNamePreferred was not actually a database field. Sorry I didn't drill down this far in the code, rookie mistake.

```
public string FirstNamePreferred
{
    get
    {
        if (FirstNameKnownAs == null)
        {
            return FirstName;
        }
        else
        {
            return FirstNameKnownAs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never put helper/domain/business logic properties in entity models. EF query translator needs to see what is behind each expression. In your case, using `FirstNamePreferred = fm.FirstNameKnownAs ?? fm.FirstName` inside projection would produce the correct SQL.

Comment: Thank @IvanStoev I'll do that.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
 var model = db.FamilyMember  
 .Where(fm => fm.UserID == message.CurrentUserID)
 .Select(fm => new 
  {
      UserID = message.CurrentUserID,
      FirstNamePreferred = fm.FirstNamePreferred
   })
   .AsNoTracking()
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Using a DTO that is not part of your DbContext will cause SELECT *

Comment: I'm still getting all the columns unfortunately. I even renamed fm to f to verify the change in SQL Profiler. This is a project that was started in 1.0.1, could there be anything I haven't done during the various upgrades that could cause this?

Comment: If FirstNamePreferred was a database column, this would work!